# Java how to sort lowercase before uppercase strings

Tags: java, sorting

I want the files to be ordered by their abs path name, but I want the lowercase to be sorted before the uppercase. Example: Let's say I got 4 files:

```
files2.add("b");
files2.add("A");
files2.add("a");
files2.add("B");
```

the order with this code is: [A, B, a, b]
I want it to be: [a, A, b, B]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class Abs {

    public ArrayList<File> getOrder(ArrayList<File> files) {
        Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
            public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
                return file1.getAbsolutePath().compareTo(file2.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        });
        return files;
    }

}
```

Comment: Should "k.txt" be smaller than "G.txt"?

Comment: Is this to be restricted to the Latin/Rnglish character set?

Comment: If you name has uppercase and lowercase char mixed? example AaAa.txt and aAAA.txt? which one should be first?

Comment: One way might be to override the compareTo method. Compare the two letters in the current position of the string as lower case. If they are equal check their normal values and give preference to the lower case.

Answer (score 6):

Check [the Collator class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html).

You'll have to read carefully what those constants mean, but one of them should make it possible for you to put lowercase letters before the upper-case letters.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use library or utility classes with this behaviour, or you can build your own comparator.

```
    new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
            // Case-insensitive check
            int comp = file1.getAbsolutePath().compareToIgnoreCase(file2.getAbsolutePath())
            // If case-insensitive different, no need to check case
            if(comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            // Case-insensitive the same, check with case but inverse sign so upper-case comes after lower-case
            return (-file1.getAbsolutePath().compareTo(file2.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: this comparator will sort [a, b, A, B] . I want [a, A, b, B]

Comment: That wasn't very clear, from your original question, but then the code becomes much simpler. Also then you can probably use library functions like the one Igor provided. Updated code

Comment: So first `compare ignore case` then only if those are equal `compare case`.  if I understand correctly: this should allow `Smith` and `smith` to be adjacent in the sorted list.  Well done.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by others, `Collator` does what you want.  Writing one of those collator rules looked a bit scary, but it looks like the standard English `Collator` does exactly what you want:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("b", "A", "a", "B");
    Collections.sort(items, Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
    System.out.println(items);
}
```

gives:

```
[a, A, b, B]
```

Answer (score 2):

Collections.sort(); lets you pass a custom comparator for ordering. For case insensitive ordering String class provides a static final comparator called CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.

So in your case all that's needed is:

Collections.sort(caps, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own `Comparator`, which in turn uses a `Collator`. See [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ComparatorusesaCollatortodeterminethepropercaseinsensitivelexicographicalorderingoftwostrings.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple implementation :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("a");
            list.add("b");
            list.add("A");
            list.add("B");
            System.out.println(list);
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                            if (o1.toLowerCase().equals(o2.toLowerCase())) {
                                    if (o1.toLowerCase().equals(o1)) {
                                            return -1;
                                    } else {
                                            return  1;
                                    }
                            } else {
                                    return o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase());

                            }
                    }
            });
            System.out.println(list);
    }
```