# Java: list sorting where a<A<b<B<...z<Z

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I used

```
Collections.sort(slist, Collator.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

and it works with "a" and "A"
for example it sorts
apple before Apple

```
 [apple, Apple]
```

However, it has this strange behavior that I couldn't understand.
if I have "AApple" and "apple", it sorts it like

```
 [AApple, apple]
```

another example is "Ahmad" and "ali" or "AA" and "aaaaa". It sorts it like

```
[Ahmad ,ali]
[A, aaaaa]
```

What I wanted is sort that makes a

for example

```
a
aa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaa
A
AAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA 
b
bbb
bbbbb
B
BBBB
```

Comment: What do you get if you sort without the collator argument?

Comment: I think with this rule a<A<b<B<…z<Z. aAa compared with aaa must be [aaa, aAa]. since a < A

Comment: Okay, so how about `aBb`?

Comment: if there is aBb and aBB I guess aBb goes first a== a B==B b<B and I think Collections.sort does.

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct.

It compares [ap] with [Ap] where [ap] should go first, then it compares [AA] with [Ap], where A is < p

Take a read about [alphanum](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) sorting methods and [natural sort order](https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/).

Comment: why doesn't it compare [A] to [a] and then [a] goes first.Thus, ignore the rest? maybe Collections wasn't the solution for my problem. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Because you used UK comparator and it forces natural sort order https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29, try using different Comprator or no at all with slist.sort();

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Usually sorts will end up with Uppercase before lowercase and I wanted the lowercase before uppercase. I found this comparator in one of the questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424394/java-how-to-sort-lowercase-before-uppercase-strings .